# How does TCP chat program both send and receive data from the same thread?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have noticed that in a few pieces of example code for a TCP chat program, written in Java, both the read string from client and send string to server both occur in main.

For example, here is a tutorial where I don't see the distinction between an input thread and in output thread... http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~amyles/tutorials/tcpchat/TCPChat.java

"BufferedReader input" and "PrintWriter output" are both used with a TCP Socket from within the same thread. As a complete novice, this confuses me because previously, if I had something that waits for input, like the "getch()" get character function from C, that thing that will hold up the thread (unless it is an event or an exception). Normally, when I imagine code in a thread being executed, I imagine it being executed line by line, with occasional jumps in execution for exceptions and events. But writing to a stream and reading from a stream is neither an exception nor an event - I don't know what the main thread would do if it received an input string and was supposed to send out an output string both at the same moment. Is the stream itself actually handled by some other thread or some other program, like the terminal or the OS?

I had felt so weird about this that I split the chat program into two separate threads to make me feel more comfortable - one thread for receiving strings from the TCP socket and another thread for sending strings out through the same socket. Can someone provide an explanation as to why my act of splitting input and output into two separate threads is totally unnecessary? And before someone marks this down due to lack of research and understanding, I did my best to read online Java tutorials on Sockets and I have had experience writing to and reading from streams (terminal and plain text file).

Comment: Can you show us the code you're talking about? You should need separate threads for this for precisely the reason you've mentioned, unless you use something like `select` to wait for input.

Comment: This is an example... http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~amyles/tutorials/tcpchat/TCPChat.java

Comment: I see the creation of a thread to handle the GUI, but I don't see the program split into one thread for input and another thread for output.

Comment: I believe everything lies at line 455: `if (in.ready()) {` as per [BufferedReader javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29) that call tells if the following read won't block. In this way the I/O thread won't block.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! So if there were two separate threads for read and write, then checking for that block wouldn't be necessary. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, is what I thought I understood right?

Comment: Your statement about `ready()` is correct. It's very poor technique: don't use it. It will still block for example if the sender sends data without a line terminator. It also appears to perform network operations on the event-dispatching thread. It's a poor piece of work. Two threads is a much better solution, or non-blocking I/O with NIO.

Comment: The *simplest* way is to use separate threads, btw. (But not the most efficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 case CONNECTED:
        try {
           // Send data
           if (toSend.length() != 0) {
              out.print(toSend); out.flush();
              toSend.setLength(0);
              changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
           }

           // Receive data
           if (in.ready()) {
              s = in.readLine();
              if ((s != null) &&  (s.length() != 0)) {
                 // Check if it is the end of a trasmission
                 if (s.equals(END_CHAT_SESSION)) {
                    changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTING, true);
                 }

                 // Otherwise, receive what text
                 else {
                    appendToChatBox("INCOMING: " + s + "\n");
                    changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           cleanUp();
           changeStatusTS(DISCONNECTED, false);
        }
        break;
```

I took this code snippet from the "main procedure" of the link you provided. 
The method that would halt the thread from continuing like you were talking about is in.readLine(); The thread would wait until there was something to read from the input stream before continuing. I would like to point out the if statement  " if(in.ready()) " By having that if statement there, the code checks first if the input stream has something to read. Otherwise, it skips over it and continues.

Comment: Note that this code can still block if the sender sends data without a line terminator. It also appears to perform network operations on the event-dispatching thread. It's a poor piece of work.